# Greedy - Locate Cottage Boxes within a distance

Tags: algorithm, greedy

An agency wants to locate boxes on a road. We have cottages on a road. Each cottage has a their own box. Each cottage's box exist at miles, x_1, x_2, ... , x_n on this road(these values can be assumed to be distinct integers that record the distance in miles from a specified origin). Our goal is to minimize the number of boxes while making sure that no cottage is further then K miles from the closest/nearest box.

Intuition: For this greedy algorithm, I want to look at each cottage one at a time, in some order, and make a greedy choose (some greedy choice) for choosing the locations of the boxes. I figured what I should do first is sort the cottage locations. But I'm struggling with the greedy choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the x_i are the distances of the cottages on the road (and not the positions of the boxes, since they aren't given and are supposed to be found). Without loss of generality the x_i are sorted. Then put the first box at distance x_1 + K along the road. This must be optimal, since there has to be a box within distance K from x_1, and wherever you put it, it can't serve more cottages than when it's maximally far away from x_1 (since there's no cottages before x_1).

Continue... let a_1 be the first cottage that's not within distance K from a box, and put the second box at distance x_{a_1} + K along the road.

In general, if you've placed i boxes, let a_i be the first house that's not within distance K from a box, and put box i+1 at distance x_{a_i} + K along the road.